# Extract TEXT from a CLOB field

Tags: oracle, extract, toad, clob

I have a CLOB field in my Oracle Database that store TEXT data in the following format:

```
__99__RU_LOCKED=N;;__99__RU_SUSPENDED=Y;;__17__USER_TYPE=A;;__17__USER_TYPE_610=A;;__17__GUIFLAG=0;;__17__DEFAULT_LANG_610=E;;__17__OUTPUT_DEVICE_46=LOCL;;__17__PRINT_IMMED=G;;__17__DELETE_AFTER_PRINT=D;;__17__CATT=*BLANK;;__17__CATT_46=*;;__17__DEC_FORMAT=*BLANK;;__17__DEC_FORMAT_46=X;;__17__DATE_FORMAT=2;;__17__PARAMETERS=OM_OBJM_NO_DISPLAYX;;__17__MEAS_EASLPFL=0;;__17__USER_GROUP=S1BR22;;__17__VALID_FROM=20080222;;__17__VALID_UNTIL=99991231;;__17__ACCOUNT=37004968;;
```

I'm using TOAD and while I am creating the query I can read the CLOB field with the following:

```
--- To read the CLOB field.
select DBMS_LOB.substr(ADD_INFO_MASTER) from USER
```

This select return me the CLOB field HUMAN READABLE.

My question is: Is there any way to extract the one single value like ACCOUNT value from the line above?
Keep in mind that this CLOB field can variate and the __17__ACCOUNT= will not be in the same place every time. I need a way to extract to locate the ;;__17__ACCOUNT= (this will be a pattern) and extract the the value 37004968.

It is possible to achieve this while performing a query in TOAD?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to deal with CLOB values larger than 4000 symbols length (Oracle 11g) or 32K length (Oracle 12c) then you must use [`DBMS_LOB` package](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28419/d_lob.htm#BABDDFDH).

This package contains [`instr()`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28419/d_lob.htm#i998546) and [`substr()`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28419/d_lob.htm#i999349) functions which operates on LOBs.

In your case query looks like that:

```
with prm as (
  select '__17__ACCOUNT' as fld_start from dual
)
select 
  dbms_lob.substr(
    text,         
    -- length of substring             
    (  
      -- position of delimiter found after start of desired field 
      dbms_lob.instr(text, ';;', dbms_lob.instr(text, prm.fld_start)) 

      -

      -- position of the field description plus it's length
      ( dbms_lob.instr(text, prm.fld_start) + length(fld_start) + 1 )
    ),

    -- start position of substring
    dbms_lob.instr(text,prm.fld_start) + length(fld_start) + 1
  )  
from 
  text_table,
  prm
```

Query above uses this setup:

```
create table text_table(text clob);

insert into text_table(text) values (
  '__99__RU_LOCKED=N;;__99__RU_SUSPENDED=Y;;__17__USER_TYPE=A;;__17__USER_TYPE_610=A;;__17__GUIFLAG=0;;__17__DEFAULT_LANG_610=E;;__17__OUTPUT_DEVICE_46=LOCL;;__17__PRINT_IMMED=G;;__17__DELETE_AFTER_PRINT=D;;__17__CATT=*BLANK;;__17__CATT_46=*;;__17__DEC_FORMAT=*BLANK;;__17__DEC_FORMAT_46=X;;__17__DATE_FORMAT=2;;__17__PARAMETERS=OM_OBJM_NO_DISPLAYX;;__17__MEAS_EASLPFL=0;;__17__USER_GROUP=S1BR22;;__17__VALID_FROM=20080222;;__17__VALID_UNTIL=99991231;;__17__ACCOUNT=37004968;;'
);
```

For everyday use with development tools it may be useful to define a function which returns value of field with desired name and use it instead of writing complicated expressions each time.
E.g. :

```
create or replace function get_field_from_text(
  pi_text       in clob,
  pi_field_name in varchar2
) return varchar2 deterministic parallel_enable
is
  v_start_pos   binary_integer;
  v_field_start varchar2(4000);
  v_field_value varchar2(32767);
begin

  if( (pi_text is null) or (pi_field_name is null) ) then
    return null;
  end if;

  v_field_start := pi_field_name || '=';
  v_start_pos := dbms_lob.instr(pi_text, v_field_start);

  if(v_start_pos is null) then
    return null;
  end if;

  v_start_pos := v_start_pos + length(v_field_start);

  v_field_value := dbms_lob.substr(
                     pi_text,
                     (dbms_lob.instr(pi_text, ';;', v_start_pos) - v_start_pos),
                     v_start_pos
                   );

  return v_field_value;
end;
```

Usage:

```
select get_field_from_text(text,'__17__OUTPUT_DEVICE_46') from text_table
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a regular expression to extract the value:

```
WITH your_table AS (
SELECT '__99__RU_LOCKED=N;;__99__RU_SUSPENDED=Y;;__17__USER_TYPE=A;;__17__USER_TYPE_610=A;;__17__GUIFLAG=0;;__17__DEFAULT_LANG_610=E;;__17__OUTPUT_DEVICE_46=LOCL;;__17__PRINT_IMMED=G;;__17__DELETE_AFTER_PRINT=D;;__17__CATT=*BLANK;;__17__CATT_46=*;;__17__DEC_FORMAT=*BLANK;;__17__DEC_FORMAT_46=X;;__17__DATE_FORMAT=2;;__17__PARAMETERS=OM_OBJM_NO_DISPLAYX;;__17__MEAS_EASLPFL=0;;__17__USER_GROUP=S1BR22;;__17__VALID_FROM=20080222;;__17__VALID_UNTIL=99991231;;__17__ACCOUNT=37004968;;' clob_field FROM DUAL
) 
SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR(clob_field,'__17__ACCOUNT=.*;;')
FROM your_table
```

Using that you would get "__17__ACCOUNT=37004968;;". You can easily extract the value with SUBSTR.

I think that in Oracle 11g REGEXP_SUBSTR has extra parameters that would let you extract a certain group within the regular expression.

Answer (score 0):

You can use INSTR and SUBSTR with CLOB datatype:

```
WITH T1 AS (
SELECT '__99__RU_LOCKED=N;;__99__RU_SUSPENDED=Y;;__17__USER_TYPE=A;;__17__USER_TYPE_610=A;;__17__GUIFLAG=0;;__17__DEFAULT_LANG_610=E;;__17__OUTPUT_DEVICE_46=LOCL;;__17__PRINT_IMMED=G;;__17__DELETE_AFTER_PRINT=D;;__17__CATT=*BLANK;;__17__CATT_46=*;;__17__DEC_FORMAT=*BLANK;;__17__DEC_FORMAT_46=X;;__17__DATE_FORMAT=2;;__17__PARAMETERS=OM_OBJM_NO_DISPLAYX;;__17__MEAS_EASLPFL=0;;__17__USER_GROUP=S1BR22;;__17__VALID_FROM=20080222;;__17__VALID_UNTIL=99991231;;__17__ACCOUNT=37004968;;' TEXT FROM DUAL
) 
SELECT SUBSTR(TEXT, 
              INSTR(TEXT, '__17__ACCOUNT=') + LENGTH('__17__ACCOUNT') + 1, -- find the first position of the value
              INSTR (TEXT, ';;', INSTR(TEXT, '__17__ACCOUNT=')) - (INSTR(TEXT, '__17__ACCOUNT=') + LENGTH('__17__ACCOUNT') + 1)  -- length to read. Difference between the end position (the first ;; after your placeholder) and the value start position (the same value as above)
             )
  FROM T1;
```

However I like the REGEXP solution proposed by pablomatico more.